# Trying to adjust alignment of figure on page in landscape style

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, positioning

I have a page in my document with the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure} [htbp]    
        \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]
        {DocsAndImages/DFD.png}}
        \caption{DFD\ldots}
        \label{fig:DFD}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

But what I'm finding is that it displays to the top of the page, i.e. given that the page is  in landscape style, the figure is too close to the left margin.

Can I change this at all to force the figure to be more central on the page?

I have tried inserting `\linebreak` and `\newline` but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\vfill`  to push the figure down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
   \null         %%<---- this is needed
   \vfill        %%<-----here
    \begin{figure} [htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
        \caption{DFD\ldots}
        \label{fig:DFD}
    \end{figure}
    \vfill        %%<----- and here
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside, `\centering` is a switch, hence `\centering {<contents>}` is wrong, it should be `\centering <contents>`.